# SignalR Alternative, Browser/Win32 Compat

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I have a browser app using signalR to connect with a browser base, kiosk, web app. Generally, it's ok, but over a long period of time we've found it's just un-reliable. The backend is not an asp.net net, it's self hosted signalR (along with the rest of the app)

Our population of units include Win7/64 and Win7/32.  It's my understanding that web sockets are not available in Win7, so server sen events/long polling are used. So any alternative would have to have this support.

What are alternatives to SignalR that would work?

Comment: What kind of reliability do you want? And which version of SignalR do you use? .NET Framework or .NET Core? There are tons of questions you didn't even go over before saying "it's just un-reliable", so I doubt any alternative can easily please you.

Comment: Support for Win7 [has ended](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information) more than a year ago, so you have an official reason not to support it anymore too

Comment: "long periods of time" "kiosk". It is entirely possible that at the scales you are talking about, TCP/IP and Ethernet/WiFi are un-reliable...

Comment: it's localhost only, we reboot every night, and it's .net 4.7.  There are a significant number of these win32s out there.  dropping support is not an option. we've gone round and round with signalr for a couple years, on the whole it generally works, does it work every single time, no.

Comment: What do you mean by unreliable? If it disconnects on the client side you can set an auto reconnect every 5 seconds. If it's just message delivery did you know that signalR messaging is not a guaranteed delivery method? You can however build in your own ping/pong send/reply to ensure your client has received and fetch the data again if not received.. Lastly, are you using the latest signalR 2.4.2?

Answer (score 0):

you can use gRPC . other signalR alternative:

```
   Pusher
   MQTT
   RabbitMQ
   WebRTC
   Kafka
   WCF
   Firebase
   Telepat
   Realtime Framework
   SockerCluster
   PubNub
   Bastly
```

https://www.educba.com/signalr-alternatives/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).